# Passing quotes in Process.Start arguments

Tags: .net, batch-file

In .NET i'm running this line

```
var p = Process.Start(@"cmd", @"/C mklink /H c:\z\b c:\z\a\");
```

This works all fine however I'm worried that if one of the two args for mklink has a space that this wont work correctly. So I added "" around both parameters. Executing this line no longer worked and when I wrote \"" instead it still didn't work.

How do I write quotes when I am executing `cmd /C`?

Comment: ah ha funny, after implementing this the very first entry in the db has a space (folder name).

Comment: You probably want to enclose the entire mklink command (with its arguments) with quotation marks, and then also the individual paths (escaping and double-escaping as appropriate).

Comment: @isturdy: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I don't exactly know what to escape except Roberts current answer doesnt appear to work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string sourcePath = @"c:\z\b";
string targetPath = @"c:\z\a";

string arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", sourcePath, targetPath);

var p = Process.Start("cmd", "/C mklink /H " + arguments);
```

Working example:

```
string sourcePath = @"c:\documents and settings\harvey robert\My Documents\Test.txt";
string targetPath = @"c:\test";

string s = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", sourcePath, targetPath);
Process.Start("cmd", @"/c copy " + s);
```

1 files copied.

Comment: I havent tried this but it looks incorrect. I wrote @"/C mklink /H ""{0}"" ""{1}""" and got an error of incorrect syntax

Comment: The line you wrote isn't going to work; the @ sign disables the \ escapes.  Try `var p = Process.Start(@"cmd", @"/C mklink /H " + "\"" + @"c:\z\b" + "\" \" " + @"c:\z\a\" + "\"");`

Comment: Why would i write it like that? `\"` simply is `""` when it is in a string with the `@` prefix

Comment: You didn't try it? :(  Try it... It's clean, and the absence of the multiple quotation marks running together keeps my head from exploding.

Comment: Isn't this what you're telling me to do? `var args = string.Format(@"/C mklink /H ""{0}"" ""{1}""", newfn, target);` But it seems like you're suggesting to do wit using "text \" " instead of doing what i currently do to add quotes

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `{0}` won't work with the `@literal` syntax.

Comment: It does. I have always used `{0}` with string. The result in my first entry is `/C mklink /H "J:\test dir_1/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" "J:\test dir/file.dat"`

Comment: Nope and thats why i wrote the question. And thats why i thought it was weird and tried using `\"` (well `\""` in my code) anyways. Still no luck

Comment: Actually maybe it does work. It might be a permission problem. Visual studios doesnt have the same permission as i do even though i'm sure no admin permissions are required. I just checked the standard error.

Comment: You're completely right. It looks like weirdness with permission on external HD. This seems to works perfectly fine when the files are on my local drive. Ah ha, I actually just didnt see the file after running it the first time then getting file already exist on other runs. The link has the same modified date and since the filename started with many 0s and this directory has lots of files that start with multiple 0s I didnt see it while typing nor looking at recently modified.