# How to start .exe file with arguments in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to start an exe file from my app in C#.

The query string should look like this:

```
Extractor.exe "base\sql" "develop" "..\Data\System" "Grids"
```

This is my code:

```
public static void StartExtractor()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = OurFields.keskullPass + @"\Extractor.Deploy\Extractor.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"base\\sql\" \"develop\" \"..\\Data\\System\" \"Grids\"";
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: look fine, sure the problem is at the arguments?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Does the command run OK without the quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A simple way to start a process with arguments in C#:**

```
Process.Start("yourapp.exe", "your arguments");
```

**If you really need to wait for process to exit, then it becomes:**

```
var process = Process.Start("yourapp.exe", "your arguments");

process.WaitForExit();
```

Usually you do not create `Process` object manually.

Process is defined in `System.Diagnostics`, so you also need to add it to your using clause.

---

And your problem is probably related to specific expectations of external application to arguments' format, or a mistake in concatenation of full path to exe.

To quote arguments you can do it manually as you did, or use a routine like that: [How to correctly escape command line arguments in c#](http://csharptest.net/529/how-to-correctly-escape-command-line-arguments-in-c/)

---

#### More examples on how to start a process:

> - [How do I start a process from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181719/how-to-start-a-process-from-c)
> - [Wait till a process ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147911/wait-till-a-process-ends)
> - [Passing quotes in Process.Start arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653991/passing-quotes-in-process-start-arguments)
> - [MSDN: Process.Start Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx)
> - [Microsoft: How to wait for a shelled application to finish by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305369) (also has an example on how to wait for process to
>     complete with timeout)