# How can I parse double quotes in this C# line?

Tags: c#, double, quotes

I need double quotes on this line for Path string:

```
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C attrib -h -s -i "+ Path +" ";
```

I tried

```
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C attrib -h -s -i "\""+ Path +""\" ";
```

and

```
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/C attrib -h -s -i "\"""+ Path +""\"" ";
```

but It didn't work, how can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal)

Comment: One of several dozen good duplicate options: [Passing quotes in Process.Start arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653991/passing-quotes-in-process-start-arguments).  By the by, that is not 'parsing', but 'escaping'

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @ symbol to stop the backslashes from being treated as literal characters rather than an escape character. Then \" can be used for the double quotes.

```
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C attrib -h -s -i \"" + Path + "\"";
```

Comment: can you help me also with this? cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C mshta vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""SAPI.SpVoice"").Speak("""+ Text +""")(window.close)") "

Comment: What's the issue? You should be able to escape double quotes now using the info above. If you want a list of other characters this is useful - https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Strings.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an @-symbol. You just have to use an escape symbol for the double quotes. Just do:

```
String Path = "The path string";
String s = "/C attrib -h -s -i \"" + Path + "\"";
```

Comment: can you help me also with this?                                                                               
            cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C mshta vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""SAPI.SpVoice"").Speak("""+ Text +""")(window.close)") ";